# How to create unique index in MongoDB that works for both upper and lower case?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is how I created unique index for my key

```
db.members.createIndex( { "name": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

but it does accept "name" : "Alex" and "name" : "alex"

is there a way to provide case sensitive and make sure there is only one alex in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Despite someone copying from the duplicate answer it's actually `strength: 2` as generally the better option for common use. And in the documentation - [Create a Case Insensitive Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/#create-a-case-insensitive-index)

Comment: yes, strength 1 will allow collation matching of characters in different accents. kiddo = kiddø

Comment: I tested strength 2 and mongoDb won't accept Alex1 eventhough it is not the same as alex. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using mongodb which version >= 3.4, you can use [`collation`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#collation-and-index-use) option:

```
db.myColl.createIndex( { category: 1 }, { unique: true, collation: { strength: 1 } } )
```